# Issue with Flask form only returning as FALSE

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

Apologies for my ignorance on the subject. I am just getting my feet wet with Web Dev with Python and Flask.

I am trying to create an app that will take a string from an input field and convert it into a hash and display it on an output page. However, I am not sure if my form is set up correctly.

When I run the application it only returns a false value and displays that the user has not inputted anything even when I type in a random string.

### app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, flash, redirect
from message import MessageForm, validators, ValidationError
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'development'

key = Fernet.generate_key()
f = Fernet(key)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    form = MessageForm(request.form)

if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate_on_submit():
    user_message = form.message_field.data
    e = user_message.encode(encoding='UTF-8')
    token = f.encrypt(e)
    output = bytes.decode(token)
    return redirect('output.html', output=output)

return render_template('index.html', form=form)

if __name__ == ('__main__'):
    app.run(debug=True)
```

### message.py

```
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField, validators
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, ValidationError

class MessageForm(FlaskForm):
    message_field = StringField('Please enter the message you would like to 
    encrypt:', [validators.Required('Please enter a message!')])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

### HTML Form

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block body %}

{{ form.csrf_token }}

<br />
<form action="/" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label style="font-weight: bold;">{{ form.message_field.label }}</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="message" id="message">
        <br />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Encrypt Message</button>
    </div>
</form>

{% for message in form.message_field.errors %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        {{ message }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}   

{% endblock %}
```

What I would like is to have the app return back an error if nothing is entered but run the application correctly if something is entered.

I hope that makes sense and as previously stated please excuse my ignorance.

Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try:

```py
user_message = request.form.get("message")
```

instead of

```py
user_message = form.message_field.data
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply and taking the time to help out. I just tried this and I sill have the same issue where it only returns FALSE and displays the error stating that the user hasn't inputted anything.

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML Form, try to put the csrf_token after the form declaration like this:

```html
<br />
<form action="/" method="POST">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label style="font-weight: bold;">{{ form.message_field.label }}</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="message" id="message">
        <br />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Encrypt Message</button>
    </div>
</form>
```